# angularjs - controller not invoking upon form submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying the below sample code to submit my form to the server.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="../js/angular.min.v1.5.5.js"></script>
   <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myController', ['$location', function($scope, $location) {
        console.log(" controller invoked ** ");
        $scope.submit = function(emp) {
        var isvalid = true;
        if (isvalid) {
            $http.put('/addEmployee', {}).then(function(result) {
                $location.path(result.data);
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }]);
</script>    
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myController">

<form name="form1"  ng-submit="form1.submit(emp)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="emp.name" />
  <div align='center'>
         <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I have started debugging the issue, I have noticed that "controller invoked **" printed once during the form loading, but not after the form submition.

Could you please help by suggesting the changes required to submit the form ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form object doesn't have `submit` method as it is available there in `$scope`, you need to call it directly. Instead of doing `form1.submit(emp)` on `ng-submit` directive, do change it to below.

```
ng-submit="submit(emp)"
```

Additionally do correct mistake in controller DI array

```
app.controller('myController', ['$location', 
   function($scope, $location) {
```

should be

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$location',  //<-- added missing $scope dependency here
   function($scope, $location) {
```

---

Pass data to put method in its 2nd parameter, currently you are passing as `{}` blank object just change it to `emp` will do the trick

```
$http.put('/addEmployee', emp).then(function(result) {
   $location.path(result.data);
});
```

Comment: No, it is still NOT working after changing to ng-submit="submit(emp)"

Comment: thanks, also, can you help me how can I pass the form data to the PUT URL ? What changes do I need to make above ?